# How can I use reflection to invoke a method on this internal class that exists in a library?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dll

I have a C# project library DLL with an internal class, and I want to unit test it. I want to specifically unit test this internal class by getting a reference to it using reflection, if possible.

I have this class:

```
namespace ProjectA.B.C
{
    class Caching
    {
        public static void DoWork() { }
    }
}
```

How can I call the `DoWork` method using reflection from another project that uses `ProjectA`? I have tried, but my first issue is that `typeof(ProjectA.B.C.Caching)` is protected so I can't seem to even get the type reference yet, but I'm sure there is a way.

The error is :

> 'ProjectA.B.C.Caching' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: It's not protected - it's internal. You can use `Assembly.GetType` though... have you tried that yet?

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated my question but still not sure how to get the assembly reference.

Comment: wablab's answer is a better approach, actually...

Comment: @JonSkeet Good approach, it works, I do like it, I will use it; still interested in a reflection answer though...which is the scope of this question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, on my way now. `Assembly.Load("ProjectA")`

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow, that was a fun exercise. Although up top it was only the simplest case, my actual methods had function parameters and generic return types so I had to use `Func<bool> action = () => { return resultToSet; };` and `MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool))` for example and invoke them. Oh and out parameters, so I had to check the parameters object. Hey, now I gained some deeper knowledge of the CLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the InternalsVisibleToAttribute to make the internal class visible to your unit test project.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good approach, it works, I do like it, I will use it; still interested in a reflection answer though...which is the scope of this question.

Comment: Assuming the assembly's name is "ProjectA", you could do:
var t = Type.GetType("ProjectA.B.C.Caching, ProjectA");
var m = t.GetMethod("DoWork");
m.Invoke(null, null);

Answer (score 0):

If the other project has the name `ProjectA.B.C` and spits out an assembly named `ProjectA.B.C`, and it has the following internal class implementation with the following method signatures and the following namespace:

```
namespace ProjectA.B.C
{
    class Caching
    {
        public static bool GetOrSet<T>(string key, Func<T> getValue, out T value, TimeSpan? expiration = null) {
            ...
        }
        public static bool Get<T>(string key, out T value) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it like this for unit testing:

```
var type = Assembly.Load("ProjectA.B.C").GetTypes().First(x => x.Name.Equals("Caching", StringComparison.Ordinal));
var methods = type.GetMethods();
var getOrSetMethod = methods.First(x => x.Name.Equals("GetOrSet", StringComparison.Ordinal) && x.ReturnType.Name.Equals("Boolean", StringComparison.Ordinal)).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool));
var getMethod = methods.First(x => x.Name.Equals("Get", StringComparison.Ordinal)).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool));
var resultToSet = true;
Func<bool> action = () => { return resultToSet; };
if (!(bool)getOrSetMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { "GetOrSet", action, resultToSet, (TimeSpan?)null }))
    throw new Exception("Could not set the GetOrSet key to a boolean value of true.");
var parameters = new object[] { "GetOrSet", resultToSet };
if (!(bool)getMethod.Invoke(null, parameters))
    throw new Exception("Could not get back the GetOrSet key.");
if ((bool)parameters[1] != true)
    throw new Exception("Got the wrong GetOrSet key back.");
```

The above shows how you can:

- Create generic function parameters.
- Invoke methods with generics by using `MakeGenericMethod(params Type[] typeArguments)`.
- Invoke methods with `out` parameters and check the returned
  parameters array for the result.